# Running nested routines concurrently in Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrency, python-multithreading, python-asyncio

I’m doing I/O operations using pySerial and some self-written post-processing modules. A request is sent to a COM port and the response is then processed and saved to a text file. Everything's works fine, but I have some difficulties running it concurrently.

It simply goes this way:

```
while True:
    serial_port.action()
    # ^ will send the data to the post-processor
    #                             ^ will send the data to the file exporter
```

### First approach: Threads

The serial port class inherits from `threading.Thread` and is started by the main method. A message broker is used by the serial port thread to send the response of the COM device to the post-processor. The post-processor uses the message broker in the same way to forward the data afterwards to the file exporter and so on.

The problem: it’s not concurrently, because the serial port thread could have been working again while the post-processor is still doing its processing stuff.

### Second approach: async/await

The classes use an asyncronous method `action()` to do their work. After the data object is processed it is send via the message broker to the (asyncronous) `action()` method of the next class.

```
# Within a while loop run:
async def action(self, *args):
    # Do some stuff...
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

    # Send the data object to the next processing module.
    # The message broker will call the action() method of the receiver.
    await self._message_next(my_data)
```

Well, that works not how intended. On the first iteration of the loop the data is processed by all classes. On the next iterations the data doesn’t leave the first `action()` method (of the serial port). Log says:

```
serial port: action()
post-processor: action()
file exporter: action()
serial port: action()
serial port: action()
serial port: action()
serial port: action()
serial port: action()
...
```

### Third approach: ThreadPoolExecutor

The next approach was to use a `ThreadPoolExecutor`. But the result is the same like in the second approach.

```
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(1)
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

try:
    asyncio.ensure_future(loop.run_in_executor(executor, serial_port.action()))
    loop.run_forever()
finally:
    loop.close()
```

### Question

What is the right approach/design to reach the described goal of doing I/O operations and post-processing stuff concurrently in Python 3.5?

## Revision of Question

Let’s say we have some routines. One is doing I/O and therefore blocking, whereas the other ones are used for data processing and are non-blocking. How can I achieve that blocking and non-blocking routines run asynchronously? Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import asyncio
import random

async def foo():
    # blocking I/O
    await asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(0, 0.5))
    print('(1) foo')

async def bar():
    # non-blocking data processing
    await sub_bar_1()
    await sub_bar_2()

async def sub_bar_1():
    await asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(0.5, 2.0))
    print('(2) sub_bar_1')

async def sub_bar_2():
    await asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(0.5, 2.0))
    print('(3) sub_bar_2')

async def main():
    while True:
        await foo()
        await bar()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

try:
    asyncio.ensure_future(main())
    loop.run_forever()
finally:
    loop.close()
```

`foo()` has to wait until `bar()` is finished:

```
(1) foo
(2) sub_bar_1
(3) sub_bar_2
(1) foo
(2) sub_bar_1
(3) sub_bar_2
```

How can `foo()` run independently and `bar()` is called after every I/O operation?

Comment: Have you tried async transport implementation in pyserial https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/blob/master/serial/aio.py

Comment: Nope, I have not. But thank you for the hint.